# Как сделать чтение и вывод из csv файла

Tags: python

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с проблемой, что не знаю как прочитать и вывести данные из файла csv на python, у меня есть код который читает и выводит совпадения из txt, можете сделать такой же только для csv?

Код:

```
bd = input('Напиши точный путь к текстовому файлу:')
search = input('Запрос:')
with open(bd, encoding='utf-8') as f:

    result = f.read()
    c = result.count(search)
    print(f'Количество совпадений {c}')
    input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')
    with open(bd, encoding='utf-8') as f:
        for line in f:
            if search in line:
                print(line.strip())
```

Comment: Вы не приняли ни одного ответа на свои вопросы. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я сделал сам.

вот код:

```
import csv

def search_in_csv(file_path, search_term):
    count = 0
    found_rows = []
    with open(file_path, newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=';')
        for row in csvreader:
            found = False
            for value in row:
                if search_term.lower() in value.lower():
                    found = True
                    break
            if found:
                count += 1
                found_rows.append(row)

    print(f"Количество совпадений: {count}")
    input('Для вывода нажми Enter...')
    
    for row in found_rows:
        print(*row, sep='|')

search_term = input('Запрос:')
search_in_csv('data.csv', search_term)
```

`data.csv` нужно заменить на название вашего файла.